# What Champions League winners had the largest and smallest overall margins during the tournament?

Tags: football, statistics, champions-league

I came across [this TalkSports article](http://talksport.com/football/worst-champions-league-winners-ever-revealed-160504194531) about undeserving champions.  But it got me wondering about a couple other ways of looking at it:

- The greatest/smallest goal differential (per game) through the course of the tournament
- The most/fewest minutes leading (per game)

It would seem these would really help quantify teams that scraped through the tournament and teams that controlled the tournament.  Getting a list of at least a few teams at each end of the spectrum, and perhaps average values, would help compare the different victors.

Comment: Why has this question been downvoted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've spent a good part of my day analyzing the matches documented in [individual CL tournament wiki pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1992%E2%80%9393_UEFA_Champions_League) and [RSSF](http://www.rsssf.com/ec/ecomp.html), and here are the results of the **greatest/smallest goal differential (per game) stats** through 1992/93 - 2017/18 Champions League seasons* (unfortunately *the most/fewest minutes leading* stats are not included, as they were too hard to count):

```
  Season |        Team       | Games | Scored | Received | Average Goal Difference per Game
 2013/14 |    Real Madrid    |   13  |   41   |    10    |               2,38
 2015/16 |    Real Madrid    |   13  |   28   |     6    |               1,69
 2010/11 |     Barcelona     |   13  |   30   |     9    |               1,62
 1992/93 |     Marseille     |    7  |   15   |     4    |               1,57
 1997/98 |    Real Madrid    |   11  |   22   |     5    |               1,55
 2014/15 |     Barcelona     |   13  |   31   |    11    |               1,54
 2012/13 |   Bayern Munich   |   13  |   31   |    11    |               1,54
 2005/06 |     Barcelona     |   13  |   24   |     5    |               1,46
 2008/09 |     Barcelona     |   13  |   32   |    13    |               1,46
 2016/17 |    Real Madrid    |   13  |   36   |    18    |               1,38
 1993/94 |       Milan       |    8  |   13   |     2    |               1,38
 2017/18 |    Real Madrid    |   13  |   33   |    16    |               1,31
 1994/95 |        Ajax       |   11  |   18   |     4    |               1,27
 2001/02 |    Real Madrid    |   17  |   35   |    14    |               1,24
 1996/97 | Borussia Dortmund |   11  |   23   |    10    |               1,18
 1998/99 | Manchester United |   11  |   29   |    16    |               1,18
 1995/96 |      Juventus     |   11  |   22   |     9    |               1,18
 2007/08 | Manchester United |   13  |   20   |     6    |               1,08
 2011/12 |      Chelsea      |   13  |   25   |    12    |               1
 2006/07 |       Milan       |   13  |   20   |    10    |               0,77
 2000/01 |   Bayern Munich   |   17  |   24   |    12    |               0,71
 1999/00 |    Real Madrid    |   17  |   35   |    23    |               0,71
 2004/05 |     Liverpool     |   13  |   18   |     9    |               0,69
 2009/10 |   Internazionale  |   13  |   17   |     9    |               0,62
 2003/04 |       Porto       |   13  |   20   |    12    |               0,62
 2002/03 |       Milan       |   17  |   21   |    14    |               0,41
```

It's worth to mention that Real Madrid's 2013/14 CL campaign delivered an outstanding result with a whooping average goal difference of **2,38** per game, as compared to average **1,21**. Moreover, with this run Real Madrid is the only CL-winner side that achieved an average goal difference greater than **2** per game.

*Note that only the games starting from the group stages were taken into account.

Comment: It's worth noting that 2017-18 Liverpool would actually be second best on this list, with 41 goals scores versus 16 received (1.92 average difference).  And there may well be other teams through the years which did not win to have a giant positive goal difference, but run into a buzzsaw.

Comment: And in fact PSG at 27 for to 9 against in 8 games (2.25 average difference) would make that spot as well.  Go figure that Real Madrid beat both.  Goes to show groups and matchups matter.  But honestly, goal difference when you didn't win doesn't mean much, so certainly still extremely happy with the data you dug up.  (And thanks for updating)

Comment: Exactly, draw results matter. Real Madrid had tough group stage and knock-out pairings (6 out of 7 opponents were top teams): Tottenham, Borussia, PSG, Juventus, Bayern Munich, Liverpool. But on average, the statistics is still balanced.